# Get Value from local .resx file

Tags: asp.net

How can i get value from local .resx file in asp.net?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From code-behind:

```
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");

// Gets the value of associated with key "MyKey" from the local resource file for a given culture ("~/MyPage.aspx.en.resx") or from the default one ("~/MyPage.aspx.resx")
object keyValue = HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("~/MyPage.aspx", "MyKey", culture);
```

If you need the value to be populated directly on your page/user control then you can use one of [these techniques](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228093(v=vs.80).aspx) to get the values from the resource files.

Comment: my .resx file inside folder like this : Module/FAQ/FAQ.asxc.resx

Comment: @Raika: Then the virtual path (the first parameter of the "GetLocalResourceObject" method) will look like this: "~/Module/FAQ/FAQ.ascx". I assume that the "Module" folder is placed in the root of your ASP.NET app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to read from your resource file. You can keep the file path in your config or make it a constant and remove it from your method. You can also make it a static method for better practice.

```
/// <summary>
/// method for reading a value from a resource file
/// (.resx file)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="file">file to read from</param>
/// <param name="key">key to get the value for</param>
/// <returns>a string value</returns>
public string ReadResourceValue(string file, string key)
{
    //value for our return value
    string resourceValue = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        // specify your resource file name 
        string resourceFile = file;
        // get the path of your file
        string filePath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();
        // create a resource manager for reading from
        //the resx file
        ResourceManager resourceManager = ResourceManager.CreateFileBasedResourceManager(resourceFile, filePath, null);
        // retrieve the value of the specified key
        resourceValue = resourceManager.GetString(key);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        resourceValue = string.Empty;
    }
    return resourceValue;
}
```