# Read a specific resx file within a ClassLibrary

Tags: asp.net, resx, class-library

I have a ClassLibrary with a C# Class and a folder with resx files.

I have to read a specific Resx file by culture within the C# class.

I tried the following code (both `GetLocalResourceObject` and `GetGlobalResourceObject`), but I get this error: 'The relative virtual path is not allowed here'.

```
HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("Folder.ResxFileName", "ResxKey", new CultureInfo("it-IT"))
```

How do I have to set the Resx file path to get it working?

(The ClassLibrary dll is referenced in a website project)

Comment: I think this may be that you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733560/get-value-from-local-resx-file

Comment: I tried it by it seems not working. The difference is the ClassLibrary, I don't have my resx files within the website, so I don't know how to get them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've just to use the ResourceManager exposed by the class library (with the namespace 'ClassWithResx'):

```
ClassWithResx.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("ResxKey", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

this works supposing you've a Resources.resx and Resources.en-US.resx (or whatelse) file in the root of your class library, and you've to mark with the custom tool the access modifier of the resource strings to "Public".

Comment: It works thanks. By the way, the resx files are read within the ClassLibrary so it works with resx marked as Internal too.