# How can i get my resource file and then get value from key in c#

Tags: c#

I have Home.aspx.hi-in.resx resource file in App_LocalResources Folder having a key "infoRes.Text"
and I am using the following code for getting value of key "infoRes.Text" in Home.aspx.cs file but getting error..!

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()    
    {
        ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Home", typeof(Home).Assembly);
        CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("hi-in");
        string s = rm.GetString("infoRes.Text", culture);
    }
```

Comment: {"Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure \"Home.resources\" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly \"WebApp\" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed."}

Comment: Have you set the "Build Action" option to "Embedded Resource" for the resource file?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this but it is still not working but thanks Kiran for your suggestion.

Comment: Now I have got my answer from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733560/get-value-from-local-resx-file